# Scan the input and start the loop again or close it

Tags: java

I programmed a Guessing Game and now I got a problem. I want to ask the User if he/she wants to play again if the answer is "y" (yes), restart the game, if the answer is "N" (No) it should end the loop.

Why won't it end if I type in "No"?
Can someone help me with this part of my code?

I've tried different things like defining it outside or inside of the class etc.

```
public class GuessingGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rdm = new Random();// Welcome to the game

    System.out.println("Welcome!");

    // Generate random number
    int input = 0;
    do {
        int rdmNumber = rdm.nextInt(999) + 1;

        while (input != rdmNumber) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter your guess:");
                int userGuess = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                input = userGuess;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a number - try again!");
            }

            if (input > rdmNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too big!");
            } else if (input < rdmNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too small!");
            } else if (input == rdmNumber) {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Play another Round? [y/N]");
        String nextRound = sc.nextLine();
        sc.next();
        if (nextRound.contains("y")) {
            input = 0;
        }

    }while (input == 0);
}
}
```

If the user types in "y" the game sould do a restart, if he/she types "N", it should end.

Comment: Presumably if the string does _not_ contain `y`, you would set `input` to something other than zero. Otherwise `input` is always zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only ever updating `input` when `nextRound.contains("y")`. Thus with any input other than "y", input will remain `0` (the value you initialized it to). The while loop continues because `input == 0` is true.

The proper solution is to change your `if` statement to:

```java
if (nextRound.contains("N")) {
    input = 1;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```java
if (nextRound.contains("N")) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response.

I changed it the way you told me but now I got the problem if I enter "y" it terminates.